# How do I get nausea and hunger potions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I get the hunger and nausea potions that are unavailable in the creative mode inventory?

I've seen Youtubers doing it but I cannot get them with commands that I have tried.

Is a mod needed to get them? If not how can I get them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mods are not needed to do this. You can get all these potions and more with commands.

For a swiftness potion:

```
/give <player> minecraft:potion 1 0 {Potion:"minecraft:swiftness"}
```

For a hunger potion:

```
/give <player> minecraft:potion 1 0 {Potion:"minecraft:hunger"}
```

For a nausea potion:

```
/give <player> minecraft:potion 1 0 {Potion:"minecraft:nausea"}
```

Comment: The "hunger" and "nausea" commands are not correct; there are no default IDs for them (default IDs being those brewed, specified via the "Potion" tag). The "CustomPotionEffects" tag must be used instead to use global IDs. Hunger (17): `/give @p minecraft:potion 1 0 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:17,Duration:100}]}` Nausea (9): `/give @p minecraft:potion 1 0 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:9,Duration:100}]}`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the effect to be amplified (e.g. Strength 4 or Speed 18 etc),
you could use this:

`/give @p potion 1 0 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:(id of the potion),Duration:(number of ticks it should last),Amplifier:(amplifier value)}]}`

If you want more than one effect, this also works:

`/give @p potion 1 0 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:#,Duration:#of ticks,Amplifier:#},{Id:#,Duration:#of ticks,Amplifier:#},{Id:#,Duration:#of ticks,Amplifier:#},{...}]}`

If the amplifier is negative, it will do the opposite effect. For example, an amplifier value of -2 on a health potion will *reduce* your maximum health. On a Strength potion, it will reduce the amount of damage you deal.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do this command to get nausea potion, and just do the same for hunger but change the 9 to 15.

```
/give @a potion 1 8256 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:9,Amplifier:10,Duration:600}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a nausea potion, use this command:

```
/give {Player} minecraft:potion 1 0 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:9,Duration:100}]}
```

As you can see my `Duration` is set to 100 is because by default, it will not last long, so just change the `Duration` into a higher number to make it last longer.

Answer (score 2):

In 1.13/1.14, it is the following:

---

```
/give @p minecraft:potion{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:9b,Amplifier:1b,Duration:1200}]} 1
```

---

Comment: The question asked for nausea *and* hunger potions. Which one is this, and do you know the command for the other one as well?

Answer (score 1):

Hunger:

```
/give @p minecraft:potion 1 0 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:17,Duration:1000}]}
```

Nausea:

```
/give @p minecraft:potion 1 0 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:9,Duration:1000}]}
```

Change the "Duration" to make it last longer or shorter.

Comment: Does this work for bedrock as well as java, or just java?

Comment: Also, does it actually use the { }, or does it use [ ] or ( )? It keeps giving me an error when I try the command, either in java or bedrock

Answer (score 0):

You can do the command

```
/effect {player} nausea {number of ticks}
```

for hunger (or other potion effect) change the "nausea" part to the effect you desire.

Comment: This would work to just apply the effect outright, but in some cases it is necessary to obtain a potion, like in the case of making an alcoholic beverage for a special map (this would be the nausea potion). There are certain effects that have no brewable potion in survival and cannot be obtained in the creative menu, which is why the question was asked in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think you should do /give @a potion 1 8256 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:9,Amplifier:10,Duration:600}]}
on older versions. Just a heads-up.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please, refrain from posting more than one answer, you can always edit the previous one.

Answer (score -1):

You can use your fishing rod to catch some pufferfish, get ready for your dinner, and eat it; cause nausea potion doesn't exists in the game.

About the hunger effect, you can eat the raw chicken, or rotten flesh.

Comment: the question asked for potions.